# How to specify condition properly in the IF statement in Robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, robotframework

I'm trying to use the IF and ELSE IF statements in ROBOT framework but i'm coming across the below error, what is correct syntax?

```
Select the All Events sub section as
    [Arguments]            ${screenName}
    IF          "${screenName}"   ==  "safety"
        click element    ${safetyScreenButton}
    ELSE IF     "${screenName}"   ==  "service"
        click element    ${serviceScreenButton}
    ELSE IF     "${screenName}"   ==  "vehicle"
        click element    ${vehicleScreenButton}
    ELSE IF     "${screenName}"   ==  "video requests"
        click element    ${videoRequestsScreenButton}
    END
```

```
Verify safety screen under all events tab
    [Tags]    safetyScreenAllEventsTabTest
    Navigate To All Events Tab
    Select the All Events sub section as   'service'
```

Error-
Multiple errors:

- IF has more than one condition.
- ELSE IF has more than one condition.
- ELSE IF has more than one condition.
- ELSE IF has more than one condition.

I tried removing the double quotes in the conditions but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I used the If condition in the below format and it worked.

```
Select the All Events sub section as
    [Arguments]            ${screenName}
    run keyword if    ${screenName}=="safety"           click element    ${safetyScreenButton}
    run keyword if    ${screenName}=="service"          click element    ${serviceScreenButton}
    run keyword if    ${screenName}=="vehicle"          click element    ${vehicleScreenButton}
    run keyword if    ${screenName}=="video requests"   click element    ${videoRequestsScreenButton}
```